# Azure C# - Update a particular entry in a row

Tags: c#, azure, azure-mobile-services

i have a table on azure and i wish to update a particular entry in the table. when I try to update the table with the .UpdateAsync(object); method, the whole row is replaced with null values and the parameters specified only gets updated

UPDATE CODE

```
 ipray_users data = new ipray_users {id= settings["userid"].ToString(), favorite = String.Format(globals.id + "#") };
 await App.MobileService.GetTable<ipray_users>().UpdateAsync(data);
```

ipray_users class

```
class ipray_users
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string gender { get; set; }       
    public string country { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string favorite { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: specifying all the properties to the class object and calling the updateAsync would be a tedious work

Comment: As far as I am aware Azure only supports a complete overwrite `Update` call - you would need to query for the particular record first, update the specific fields, and then pass that as the parameter.

Comment: yes James, this is indeed a disadvantage because everytime I make an update, I have to make the call to the server twice; 1 for retriving the existing the data, another for updating it. It would be great if Microsoft could come up with a workaround for this issue.

Comment: wouldn't you have had to make a pull first anyway to pull the user id? Regardless, I agree, there is definitely a more optimal solution where it would only update the properties that are present.

Comment: If you do not want to fetch, update, SaveChanges etc, for a single field update, you may be better off going back to executing a SQL string query.  That or add a Stored Proc to do the work, in a single operation, and call it using EF :)

Comment: You could also make a class with just the fields you care about and pass that in. (the server call is a PATCH, so if the class doesn't have a field it will be left as is)  Or as Carlos mentions below, use the jobject for one off type updates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to update only a certain subset of properties of your object, you can use the "untyped" (JSON) overload of the `UpdateAsync` call, which lets you pass a JSON object with only the properties that you want updated. In your example, it would look something like the code below:

```
JObject data = new JObject {
    { "id", settings["userid"].ToString() },
    { "favorite", String.Format(globals.id + "#") }
}
await App.MobileService.GetTable<ipray_users>().UpdateAsync(data);
```